# Where to enter access token in PAW

Tags: header, authorization, unauthorized, paw-app, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I want to perform a GET request in a paw file that I have got from former developers, and need to enter my accesstoken. Any idea where I should enter it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the kind of authorization you're using. But as it appears on this screenshot, you're using a `Authorization` header with a `Bearer` token, which suggests you're using OAuth 2.

I suggest that you setup Paw to use an OAuth 2 authorization scheme as described in this documentation article: https://paw.cloud/docs/auth/oauth2